# Advice on efficient ElasticSearch document design

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on a project that deals with listings (think: Craiglist, Ebay, Trulia, etc).

The basic unit of information is a "Listing", something like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "title": "Awesome apartment!",
   "price": 1000000,
   // other stuff
}
```

*Some* fields can be searched upon (e.g price, location, etc), others are just for display purposes on the application (e.g title, description which contains lots of HTML etc).

My question is: should i store all the data in one document, or split it into two (one for searching e.g 'ListingSearchIndex', one for display, e.g 'ListingIndex').

I also have to do some pretty hefty aggregations across the documents too.

I guess the question is, would searching across smaller documents then doing another call to fetch the results by id be faster than just searching across the full document?

The main factors is obviously speed, but if i split the documents then maintenance would be a factor too.

Any suggestions on best practices?

Thanks :)

Comment: In my experience with Elasticsearch, shard configuration

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Elasticsearch, shard configuration has been significant in cluster performance/ speed when querying, aggregating etc. Since, every shard by itself consumes cluster resources (memory/cpu) and has a cost towards cluster overhead it is ideal to get the shard count right so the cluster is not overloaded. Our cluster was over-sharded and it impacted loading search results, visualizations, heavy aggregations etc. Once we fixed our shard count it worked flawlessly!

https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster

*Aim to keep the average shard size between a few GB and a few tens of GB. For use-cases with time-based data, it is common to see shards between 20GB and 40GB in size.*

*The number of shards you can hold on a node will be proportional to the amount of heap you have available, but there is no fixed limit enforced by Elasticsearch. A good rule-of-thumb is to ensure you keep the number of shards per node below 20 to 25 per GB heap it has configured. A node with a 30GB heap should therefore have a maximum of 600-750 shards, but the further below this limit you can keep it the better. This will generally help the cluster stay in good health.*

Answer (score 0):

Besides performance, I think there's other aspects to consider here.

ElasticSearch offers weaker guarantees in terms of correctness and robustness than other databases (on this topic see their blog post [ElasticSearch as a NoSQL database](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql)). Its focus is on search, and search performance.

For those reasons, as they mention in the blog post above:

> Elasticsearch is commonly used in addition to another database

One way to go about following that pattern:

- Store your data in a primary database (e.g. a relational DB)
- Index only what you need for your search and aggregations, and to link search results back to items in your primary DB
- Get what you need from the primary DB before displaying - i.e. the data for display should mostly come from the primary DB.

The gist of this approach is to **not treat ElasticSearch as a source of truth**; and instead have another source of truth that you index data from.

Another advantage of doing things that way is that you can easily reindex from your primary DB when you change your index mapping for a new search use case (or on changing index-time processing like analyzers etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't answer this question without knowing all your queries in advance. For example consider that you split to documents and later you decide that you need to filter based on a field stored in one index and sort by a field that is stored in another index. This will be a big problem!

So my advice to you, If you are not sure where you are heading, just put everything in one index. You can later reindex and remodel.